# Why does a stronger US dollar translate to potentially lower sales and earning for Microsoft?

Tags: microeconomics, currency, international-economics, exchange-rates, software

A recent headline stated:

> "Microsoft Corp. cut sales and earnings guidance for the fourth
> quarter, citing unfavorable foreign exchange rates as the stronger
> U.S. dollar takes a toll."

*Source: Wall Street Journal*

Why does a stronger U.S. dollar mean potentially *lower* sales and earning for a company like Microsoft?

Comment: Because Microsoft sells a lot of its products abroad (outside of the US), in all sorts of currencies.

Comment: Hi downvoter.  As you can see, this was my first post on this SE.  Would you care to be helpful and explain how this question can be improved before just casting a downvote?  Downvoting without any feedback leads to the deterioration of this site, as it makes people less likely to participate.  Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. If you google "Why does a stronger U.S. dollar mean potentially lower sales" you will get your answer. e.g. [Investopedia 1](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/economics/09/how-us-benefits-when-dollar-falls.asp) - although there are usually plenty of  inaccuracies in investopedia articles (although Nestle & Unilever are European, they are not from countries where the EUR is used for example) it still explains the underlying mechanics.

Comment: [Yahoo finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/news/strong-vs-weak-dollar-impacts-160000310.html?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAAEdW_gKBCxzJv5IQ7U5wEUxZ1wYb9iQIOmDFJ6cE5_xL_hdHb6yyHSP42ytn3xJa5ubKCSRJIHtekIM_YVHVQJqqjYs-Yhvqv7-cHRjt4sYgOTQcbHOU8lHolkxJaU53l7mp_kPDFMxJcA8Ik_BVVibJC42C1BHl0JDFBWfzK7N) should also help. Essentially (almost) every search result should work. If it explains it with a weak dollar, the case of a strong dollar is in essence just the opposite.

Comment: @AKdemy Thank you for your feedback.  That is all useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this depends on the demand elasticity of foreign purchasers. BUT, assuming Microsoft doesn't change prices, I assume it means less rev for Microsoft because, if Microsoft sold its software for 10 euros before -- this would mean $12 in USD (for example).

If the dollar becomes stronger vis-a-vis the Euro, 10 euro now only converts to $11 USD. Thus, in this simple example, Microsoft's sales go down because the dollar is stronger (i.e. its foreign sales convert into less USD)